# Get application input idle time

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I would like to get the idle time of my Windows Forms application (not the system). This will enable me to update the database to show which users are online/offline amongst other things.

I have searched extensively here, googled, and have come up empty handed.

Comment: define idle time of your winforms.

Comment: @laptop - the elapsed time since a user made an input using mouse/keyboard etc.

Comment: This can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580566/how-to-determine-the-last-time-a-user-input-was-received-in-silverlight-3 alse see http://joelabrahamsson.com/entry/detecting-mouse-and-keyboard-input-with-net

Comment: Use the aptly named Application.Idle event to store DateTime.Now.  Idle time is the current DateTime.Now minus that value.

Comment: @Hans - Your comment was the answer I was looking for, can you post it as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to me is to monitor for mouse and keyboard events and update some static variable, [see](http://joelabrahamsson.com/entry/detecting-mouse-and-keyboard-input-with-net). I'm not sure if you need to go so deep to Win32 calls, maybe you'll be just fine with standard .NET events.

As Hans Passant noted you can use [`Application.Idle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.idle%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) static event. However be sure to deattach it in `Application.Exit` event, to avoid memory leaks.

P.S. for C# to VB.NET translation you can [use this](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html).